# How can I force my webpage to open in iOS Safari instead of an in-app UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview, mobile-safari

The in-app UIWebView is limited in iOS. If I'm seeking to take advantage of features inaccessible by UIWebView on my website, how can I force a link to open a page in iOS Safari instead?

For example, assume my web page includes the following:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Open in Safari</a>
```

If someone is browsing this page in another app (let's say Google Chrome or Twitter for iOS), how can I force Safari to open this link instead?

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate the native behavior, and communicate the desired behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/gXLjF/

Open this from iOS Google Chrome (or any other non-Safari iOS browser) to see for yourself:
http://jsfiddle.net/gXLjF/embedded/result/

I've seen many questions here from the app developer's perspective, but how about from the web site's perspective.  Is there a proper `target` attribute to trigger this action?  Or a JavaScript function to force this behavior?